# Cannot dismiss Modal View Controller after trying several options

Tags: ios, view, dismiss

Hi have this problem of a view that cannot be closed. I have read a lot of Q&As and I tried

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

once it did not work I have tried calling the parent view:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

then there was a discussion on what is working on iOS 5 and later and I tried this code:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]){
     [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 } else {
     [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

The last thing I have tried was adding the following code to make the call from the main thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismissSelf) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Eventually, I have no solution to the problem as nothing works for me.
I will be glad to see the "killer" line that makes it to work.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: How did you present it in the first place?

Comment: _fav = [[FavoritesActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesActivityViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:_fav.view];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem (based on your comment) is you are technically not using a modal, you are using a subview!

If you want to use a modal you need to do:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.fav animated:YES];
```

to present your controller, instead of: `[self.view addSubview:_fav.view];`

Then your dismissal will work (many of your solutions will work):

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Otherwise if you do wish to use a subview you would need to do this to remove it:

```
[self.fav.view removeFromSuperview];
```

(It also looks like you are using ivars. If you wish to keep using them then replace `self.fav` with `_fav`)

Comment: If I understand correctly the following line:
[self.fav.view removeFromSuperview];
should be called at the parent view while I get the selector on the subview itself. How do I make the parent to call this command from the subview?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have some action (say a button) that is triggered in the `childViewController` (`fav`) that should remove the subview (`fav.view`), correct? In that case you will want to look into `delegates` and `protocols`. Otherwise you could just call `[self.view removeFromSuperView];` in `fav`. (Also, if you are attempting to use modals you should probably take the modal approach, then you could just use the `dismissModalView...` in `fav` as well).

Comment: Trying to run this code ( [self.view removeFromSuperView];) in fav causes a compile error stating that removeFromSuperView is not visible in UIView. Do I have to include some header file?

Comment: do not capitalize `View` in `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: No problem, if you want automatic animations or anything like that take a look at using modals. Otherwise, cheers!